# Вывод аватарки после ввода ника

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Я новичок в html и в node
в `play.ejs` у меня есть блок с формами ввода и пароля, выглядит он вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я хочу сделать: Хочу чтобы поле с вводом никнейма постоянно слушалось и подставляла то, что находится в поле - в ссылку, и картинку с содержимым появлялась где-то рядом
Реализовать хочу через `https://minotar.net/avatar/`

Мой код на данный момент:

```
<div class="registracia1">
            <h1 class = "osnovareg" >Шаг 2. Введите ник </h1>
            <h2 class="Helperrr">Введите никнейм вашей лицензированной учетной записи.</a></h2>
        </div>

            <div class="nickname1">
                <input class="play-border play-input" type="text" id="skinname" placeholder="Введите никнейм" v-model="nickname">
            </div>

            <div class="play-error" v-if="error > 0 && error < 3">
                <div v-if="error === 1">
                    <p>Ник должен состоять от 3 до 16 букв</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else-if="error === 2">
                    <p>Ник не должен содержать специальных символов</p>
                </div>
                <img src="assets/img/error.png">
            </div>
            <button class="play-button" type="submit">Авторизация</button>
            <div class="play-error" v-if="error >= 3">
                <div v-if="error === 3">
                    <p>Игрок с таким ником не существует</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else-if="error === 4">
                    <p>Игрок с таким ником уже зарегистрирован</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else-if="error === 5">
                    <p>Ошибка с сервером</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else-if="error === 6">
                    <p>Вас нет в дискорд сервере</p>
                </div>
                <img src="assets/img/error.png">
            </div>
        </from>
```

Как худо-бедно это должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]